# Why does this onchange function not work with option:selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This has to be simple: why does this on change function not work with `option:selected`?

And, why does my variable `state` not "reload" on change of the option?

```js
var states = ["AL", "AK", "AZ", "VT"];

$('#shipping_state').on('change', function() {

  var state = $("#shipping_state option:selected").text();
  console.log(state);

  jQuery("#shipping_state_field").append("<div id=\"no-ship-state\">Sorry, due to " + state + " state law, alcohol can't be shipped to a " + state + " address</div>");

  if (states.includes($(this).val())) {
    jQuery("#no-ship-state").show();
  } else {
    jQuery("#no-ship-state").hide();
  }
});
```

```css
#no-ship-state {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="shipping_state" id="shipping_state" data-label="State / County">
  <option value="">Select an option&hellip;</option>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
  <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
</select>

<div id="shipping_state_field"></div>

<div id="no-ship-state"></div>
```

Comment: Sure seems to work. See the snippet demo logs.

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it?

Comment: Hmmm.... but the no-ship-state div doesn't reappear on change with the same state name as the option.

Comment: The div is empty, how can you tell?

Comment: Ah, try the snippet now.

Comment: You're appending the "shipping_state_field" over and over again. I'd recommend instead using a div in your markup that you edit whenever necessary instead of adding a new one every time you want the text to appear.

Comment: In addition to @FelixGerberding comment: If you have multiple elements with the same ID you have undefined behaviour and different browsers will act differently. You should only have one element per id

Comment: @FelixGerberding sounds good; how would I do that?

Comment: *"but the no-ship-state div doesn't reappear"* - Yes it does.  At least, the **first** one in the DOM does.  When re-using the same `id` the behavior is technically undefined, and browsers will usually just reference the first element with that `id`.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I've added a complete answer with one way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're appending the "shipping_state_field" over and over again. I'd recommend instead using a div in your markup that you edit whenever necessary instead of adding a new one every time you want the text to appear. The example below tries to stay as close as possible to your original code:

```js
var states = ["AL", "IL", "MI", "MS", "UT", "VT", "NH"];

$('#shipping_state').on('change', function() {

  var state = jQuery("#shipping_state option:selected").text();

  jQuery("#no-ship-state").html("Sorry, due to " + state + " state law, alcohol can't be shipped to a " + state + " address");

  if (states.includes($(this).val())) {
    jQuery("#no-ship-state").show();
  } else {
    jQuery("#no-ship-state").hide();
  }
});
```

```css
#no-ship-state {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="shipping_state" id="shipping_state" data-label="State / County">
  <option value="">Select an option&hellip;</option>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
</select>

<div id="shipping_state_field"></div>

<div id="no-ship-state"></div>
```

This way `.html()` is used to replace the content of the div instead of appending an new one every time. Here's some references about the details:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append

https://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. Now I have to decide which of the two answers is somehow best :)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments, you should't append the DIV each time the user selects from the dropdown, as this creates duplicate IDs.

Create the DIV statically, and just update the name of the state in it. Then hide or show it.

```js
var states = ["AL", "AK", "AZ", "VT"];

$('#shipping_state').on('change', function() {

  var state = $("#shipping_state option:selected").text();
  console.log(state);

  if (states.includes($(this).val())) {
    $(".state_name").text(state);
    jQuery("#no-ship-state").show();
  } else {
    jQuery("#no-ship-state").hide();
  }
});
```

```css
#no-ship-state {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="shipping_state" id="shipping_state" data-label="State / County">
  <option value="">Select an option&hellip;</option>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
  <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
  <option value="NY">New York</option>
</select>

<div id="no-ship-state">Sorry, due to <span class="state_name"></span> state law, alcohol can't be shipped to a <span class="state_name"></span> address</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. Now I have to decide which of the two answers is somehow best :)